# Use faker_file to seed Images to each item in databse

Tags: python, database, flask-sqlalchemy, faker

I am attempting to use faker and fakerfile to seed a databse. All of the data except for the image can be generated normally using faker and has been working. However I am unsure how to implement faker_file (or if faker_file is even the right package to use)to generate random images for each tour.

```
import random
import tempfile
from faker import Faker

from faker_file.providers.jpeg_file import JpegFileProvider as fakeJPEG
from faker_file.storages.filesystem import FileSystemStorage as sysStore
from app import app
from models import db, Artist, Tour, Venue, Concert, User, UserConcert

FS_STORAGE = sysStore(
    root_path=tempfile.gettempdir(),
    rel_path="tmp",
)


fake = Faker()
fake.add_provider(fakeJPEG)

def make_tours():
    Tour.query.delete()
    
    for _ in range(20):
        db.session.add(Tour(
            name=fake.text(max_nb_chars=20),
            artist_id=random.randint(0, len(Artist.query.all()) - 1),
            img=fakeJPEG(fake).jpeg_file(storage=FS_STORAGE)
            
        )
        
    )
    db.session.commit() 
FS_STORAGE.exists(Tour.img)
```

Ive quite a few things. The above code is my most recent attempt. Current error is:
`Traceback (most recent call last): File "seed.py", line 41, in <module> FS_STORAGE.exists(Tour.img) File "/home/nolan/Development/code/phase projects/phase-4-full-stack-project/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/faker_file/storages/filesystem.py", line 90, in exists if os.path.isabs(filename): File "/home/nolan/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/lib/python3.8/posixpath.py", line 62, in isabs s = os.fspath(s) TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not InstrumentedAttribute`

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. Just cast the value to `str`.

```py
import random
import tempfile
from faker import Faker
from faker_file.providers.jpeg_file import JpegFileProvider
from faker_file.storages.filesystem import FileSystemStorage

from app import app
from models import db, Artist, Tour, Venue, Concert, User, UserConcert

# Initialize the file system storage to be used
FS_STORAGE = FileSystemStorage(
    root_path=tempfile.gettempdir(),
    rel_path="tmp",
)


fake = Faker()
fake.add_provider(JpegFileProvider)

def make_tours():
    Tour.query.delete()
    
    for _ in range(20):
        # Generate an image file with fake data.
        fake_image = fake.jpeg_file(storage=FS_STORAGE)
        db.session.add(
            Tour(
                name=fake.text(max_nb_chars=20),
                artist_id=random.randint(0, len(Artist.query.all()) - 1),
                img=str(fake_image),  # Cast value to string
            )
        )
    db.session.commit() 
FS_STORAGE.exists(str(Tour.img))
```

Note, that `fake_image` is an instance of `StringValue`,
which is basically a string, but does contain own flavour.
In some cases, it's best to cast its' value to string,
when you need a guaranteed string. The `StringValue`
does contain some useful meta-data inside the `data`
property. For instance, fake_image.data["filename"] would
contain the absolute path to the generated file and the
fake_image.data["content"] would contain text the file
was generated from.

Additionally, on Linux, files will be generated inside `/tmp/tmp/`
directory (first `/tmp` comes from `root_path=tempfile.gettempdir()` and the second `tmp` comes from `rel_path="tmp"`). The `root_path` should be typically the path
to your project `MEDIA_ROOT` directory (when speaking in
terms of Django) and `rel_path` is relative path to the
sub directory to store the file (from within the `MEDIA_ROOT`).
When casting to string, `root_path` is ignored.

P.S. I do recommend using [factory_boy](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) when working with ORMs directly. See [the following example](https://github.com/barseghyanartur/faker-file/blob/main/examples/sqlalchemy_example/sqlalchemy_factories/faker_file_admin_upload.py#L113).